# Imageflow path is wrong because it adds the one from the HTML

Tags: php, javascript, path, imageflow

I have included a PHP script in a Typo3 site. This PHP script genereates the img tags, which is automatically taken as base for the [imageflow-slider](http://finnrudolph.de/ImageFlow/Installation).

The imageflow files are in the folder /fileadmin/teamtemplate. The images in /fileadmin/teamtemplate/images.

In the imageflow.js I have the following parameters:

```
this.defaults =
{
    imagePath:          '',                                    /* Path to the images relative to the reflect_.php script */
    reflectPath:        'fileadmin/teamtemplate/',             /* Path to the reflect_.php script */
```

In the output of the html-file I have the following:

```
  img  src="./images/1317986502.png" ongdesc="" width="380" height="253" alt="" />
```

(Sorry, but I didn't found out how to post HTML code.) Imageflow creates the following path, which is working:

```
fileadmin/teamtemplate/reflect3.php?img=./images/1317986502.png
```

**The problem is the following:**

For the reflect3.php the path is correct, because (./images) is accessible:

-reflect3.php
-images/
--1317986502.png

Imageflow generally takes the URL given in the html img src tag. reflect3.php can now access the images, but in the html code the path is wrong!

**Wrong in HTML, but working because reflect3.php finds the files**
    img  src="./images/1317986502.png" ongdesc="" width="380" height="253" alt="" />

**Correct in HTML, but reflect3.php cannot find the files**
    img  src="./fileadmin/teamtemplate/images/1317986502.png" ongdesc="" width="380" height="253" alt="" />

**Faulty code in imageflow.js**

```
version = (my.reflectionPNG) ? '3' : '2';
src = my.imagePath+node.getAttribute('src',2);
src = my.reflectPath+'reflect'+version+'.php?img='+src+my.reflectionGET;
node.setAttribute('src',src);
```

my.reflectionGET should explode the string so that it takes only the last 1317986502.png.

**Working Solution:**

```
/* Add 'reflect.php?img=' */
if(my.reflections === true)
{
    version = (my.reflectionPNG) ? '3' : '2';
    if(my.imagePath === "") {
        src = my.imagePath+node.getAttribute('src',2);
        src = my.reflectPath+'reflect'+version+'.php?img='+src+my.reflectionGET;
    } else {
        var imagePath = node.getAttribute('src',2);
        var slash = "/";
        var lastOccurence = imagePath.lastIndexOf(slash);
        var withoutPath = imagePath.substring(lastOccurence, imagePath.length);
        src = my.imagePath+withoutPath;
        src = my.reflectPath+'reflect'+version+'.php?img='+src+my.reflectionGET;
    }
    node.setAttribute('src',src);
}
```

Comment: Imageflow is a widely used library, so I doubt it has faulty code. I honestly can't make heads or tails of your question. `At the same time the code is also given as HTML but wrong because it should be...` ??? Just make your question consist of your folder structure, your imageflow instantiation code and your current output. The rest is confusing.

Comment: Imageflow worked as standalone plugin, but the integration failed. I'd developed a solution (see my question), which seems to work for me. If you read the code you know what I mean. Also I've removed many things from my question. The reason why it was so confusing is that I analyzed the problem and developed a solution while writing the question. I gave examples and what the output would be. Also I'm wasting two hours for a path problem like this - so I was in hurry ..

Comment: Ah, I see. Glad that you got it working. Funny, I wrote a Wordpress image-flow plugin myself last year for my wife's blog. Share it with the world!

Comment: "Imageflow is a widely used library, so I doubt it has faulty code." I have never noticed that because a piece of software - even OS software - is widely used, that it is necessarily bug free. The bug that "tester" describes is real - I first noted it about 2 years go and worked around it by including the folder name in each item's IMG tag. Thanks for the patch, tester :)